# Google Analytics Goals and Tag Manager Events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I set Event tags in my Tag manager, and when I go to G-Analytics, I'm able to track those events in real-time, but the Goals associated to them never register.
I really don't know what I may be doing wrong...

[image]

[image]

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Make sure there are no extra spaces before or after your event parameters, and that the Goal parameters are nothing short of exact. Also, you won't see goals in the standard reports yet, but you should see them in your real-time conversions report. Try also to see if there is a conversion with just the Cat and Act, or just with Cat even. That will help you see if there are issues with the other values.

Comment: I can track Conversions in real-time, everything looks okay there, I fill out forms with my phone and it appears. But they don't seem to register afterwards in the other views/reports.I remember that I tracked a few of these events yesterday afternoon and yet, when I look at the graphs they now tell me that no conversions happened yesterday.

Comment: Might you have a filter that is filtering out your own visits (and hence conversions etc.) or possibly a segment applied? Also, worth mentioning that to allow up to 24 hours for data to be processed into the standard reports.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : Literally wait 24 hours for data to come in.

Thank you @nyuen for your help. I think I've found what wasn't working. I was simply impatient due to leaving for vacation and wanting it to work before I went. I had started testing yesterday afternoon and I didn't think that the "24 hours" wait before data appeared was so literal. Conversions from yesterday are just coming in now.

Sorry for panicking and thanks again !